# How to use an array with setState?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I am currently using the following to map my array to setState but nothing is getting set and no errors are being logged. If I explicitly write it out line by line, it works. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to go about this?

**Set State with Array: (Does not setSate)**

```
const myData = ['message', 'photo', 'isLoggedInhoto'];
const newData = [];

{[...Array(myData.length)].map((x, index) =>
  newData.push(myData[index])
)}

this.setState({
  newData: localStorage.getItem(newData),
})
```

**Line by line (This works and does setState):**

```
this.setState({
  message: localStorage.getItem('message'),
  photo: localStorage.getItem('photo'),
  isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
})
```

Comment: Lots of problems here. `getItem` takes a string, not an object. You also haven't set newData into localStorage. Also what are you trying to accomplish? You can clone an array with myData.slice(), or [...myData] in es6

Comment: I see. Your goal is to setState with an array of items from localstorage based on names

Comment: Data is being set in the constructor...Problems, yes. Hence the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an array as key of an object and as parameter of `getItem`.

You need to loop through `newData` and use the [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax:

```
newData.forEach(key => this.setState({ [key]: localStorage.getItem(key) }))
```

Or in refactoring your code, you can achieve it with a single loop and a single `setState` call:

```
const myData = ['message', 'photo', 'isLoggedInhoto']
const newData = {}

{[...Array(myData.length)].map((x, index) =>
  newData[myData[index]] = localStorage.getItem(myData[index])
)}

 this.setState(newData)
```

Comment: Both of them worked. I went with ---- const myData = ['message', 'photo', 'isLoggedIn'];
        myData.forEach(key => this.setState({ [key]: localStorage.getItem(key) })) -- Worked, Thank you GG!!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't deconstruct arrays in the way your code assumes they do, unfortunately. You can't set an array as a key for an object and have it expand to all the items in the array. Your code is simply setting a key named `newData`, not setting an array of keys. Javascript keys in object literals don't have to be quoted. This is using the string "newData", not the variable.

For `localStorage.getItem()`, the first argument is the string key name. You cannot get multiple keys at once by using an array as the key.

This is a clean way to do it, using ES6 syntax:

```
this.setState(
    [ 'message', 'photo', 'isLoggedInhoto' ].reduce( ( memo, key ) => ({
        ...memo,
        [ key ]: localStorage.getItem( key )
    }), {} )
);
```

Explanation:

We're **reducing** an array, which sounds like what it does. It reduces all items in the array into one thing. The first argument `memo` is the "accumulator", meaning the thing we're reducing to and building on as we go, and the second item is the current element (`'message'`, `'photo'`, etc).

An arrow function with this syntax `() => ({})` means return an object. Specifically the parenthesis wrapping the curly braces. Without the parenthesis wrapping, as in `() => {}`, then anything inside the curly braces is interpreted as a regular function body.

This syntax:

```
{ ...memo }
```

Means copy the contents of the old object `memo` into a new object. This is the es6 spread operator.

Finally, to set a key based on a variable name, wrap it in `[]`, as in

```
{ [ key ]: ... }
```

So if key is `'message`', it will create an object with `{ message: ... }`

The whole code will produce an object like

```
{
    message: localStorage.getItem('message'),
    photo: localStorage.getItem('photo'),
    isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
}
```

Which is then passed to `setState` so all keys are set correctly.

Additionally, `.map()` should not be used in this way in general. `.map()` is meant to be used to return a new array with the old values mapped to some new values. Discarding the return from `.map()` means you are using the wrong loop paradigm.

`[].forEach()` is appropriate for loops that don't return anything and instead have side effects (like pushing to some higher scope array). But in this case neither is ideal, `.reduce()` is more semantically correct to produce an object based on an array.

Comment: Thanks, Andy that works too!! Only a week in react and es6...:)

Comment: This answer is more semantically correct and does not call setState multiple times. Shorter is not always better ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a new state object, with properties from a list, and data extracted from `localStorage` using the list as keys.

1. Iterate the list using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. On each iteration create a new object, with a key from the list, and
   get the data from `localStorage`. Don't forget to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) if
   you've stored a stringified JSON data,
3. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the array and create a new object using [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
4. Set resulting object to your state.

**The code:**

```
const myData = ['message', 'photo', 'isLoggedInhoto'];
const state = Object.assign({}, ...myData.map((prop) => ({
  [prop]: localStorage.getItem(prop) // or JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(prop)) if your storing a JSON
})));

this.setState(state);
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, getting this console error however. "Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0(…)"

Comment: Your not storing a non JSON data, so `JSON.parse()` can't parse. Remove  `JSON.parse()` and it will work.

Comment: I've made `JSON.parse()` optional in the answer.

Comment: Check what `JSON.stringify() `, and `JSON.parse()` do. You'll need them for storing objects, and arrays in localStorage, or sending them using AJAX calls.